# Inner join with big table slowing down query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

A query executred by my application on a particular customer is very slow.
I realized that the customer has lots of records expecially in one table.

the query is something like this

```
SELECT T1.Field1,BT.Field2, T3.Field3
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN
BIGTABLE BT ON FIELDS INNER JOIN
TABLE2 T2 ON FIELDS
```

I noticed that commenting like this turns out in a much faster query:

```
SELECT T1.Field1,/*BT.Field2,*/ T3.Field3
FROM TABLE1 T1 /*INNER JOIN
BIGTABLE BT ON FIELDS*/ INNER JOIN
TABLE2 T2 ON FIELDS
```

So i tried this trick to reduce the size of the BIGTABLE:

```
--I use top 10 while the BIGTABLE contains 150000 records
SELECT top 10 * 
INTO #BIGTABLE
FROM BIGTABLE

SELECT T1.Field1,BT.Field2, T3.Field3
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN
#BIGTABLE BT ON FIELDS INNER JOIN
TABLE2 T2 ON FIELDS

DROP TABLE #BIGTABLE
```

Before executing this i was expecting a much faster query, but the execution time was quite similar.
Could you please suggest a way to study the performance?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably just need indexes on the columns used in the joins.

Comment: I wouldn't consider 150,000 records to be a "big" table, especially for SQL Server.  Can you post the execution plan?  Could be anything, but the stats or an index may be off.  Also post the schema, if you're joining on unindexed, large varchar fields you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Watch the first 2 (or all) of the videos here: That will help you out a lot: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/think-like-engine-class-now-free-open-source/

Comment: what's the type of the join columns? are the joins based on equality? which columns are the indexes of the tables being joined?

Answer (score 0):

To study the performance, you could do few things:

If you running the query from SSMS then simply include the Actual Execution Plan (check a small icon in the toolbar) before running the query and run it. Look at the sqlplan or you could it post it here. Sometimes there could "Table scans" or other resource consuming operations that is causing slowness. The plan will help you understand.

Apart from your query there could be other things running on the server, In the past I have used [Who Is Active Script from Adam Machanic](http://whoisactive.com) to find what other things are keeping the server busy. See if your SPID is being blocked by other queries (If you run Adam's script it has a blocking_session column that will show you that). You need almost DBA privilege to run the script. Some folks don't recommend running this script often on production servers.

You could use "WITH (READUNCOMMITED)" hint to see if that helps. This is not recommended if you don't want to see dirty data in your query.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I pasted the plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1MIB96Mb can you tell something?

Comment: EVA_REFERENCES is the big table

Comment: If you want to select only MF.ID_FUNZIONE and PA.ID_DIPENDENTE then you could try this query:

`select MF.ID_FUNZIONE,PA.ID_DIPENDENTE from 
PER_ANAGRAFICA PA INNER JOIN
MSQ_PERS_FUNZIONI MPF ON MPF.ID_DIPENDENTE = PA.ID_DIPENDENTE AND PA.STATO = 1 INNER JOIN 
MSQ_FUNZIONI MF ON MF.ID_FUNZIONE = MPF.ID_FUNZIONE 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EVA_REFERENCES ER INNER JOIN
    APP_SSHSR APP ON APP.ID_REF_IS_SS_PERIODICO_MANSIONI = ER.ID_EVA_REFERENCE_TYPES
    WHERE ER.ID_FOR_ALL = MF.ID_FUNZIONE  )`